# How to get a new input after adding end='' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When try to print the output on same line python using end=''
but after printing the same line i want get the output from new line

Here is my code

```
loop=int(input())
while loop>0:
    in_val=input()
    leni = len(in_val)
    while leni>0:
        print(in_val[leni-1],end='') # Here printed the same line 
        leni-=1 # Here the loop ends
        #in_val=input() I want to get this from new line not on same line
    loop-=1
```

Any one pls give a clue or something

Input must be like following:

```
2
234
542
```

Output:

```
432
542
```

Answer (score 4):

The `end` parameter of the `print` function has a very simple job, it adds its value to the end of the given string. By default, the value of `end` is set to '\n' which is a newline character.

---

Therefore, when you run:

```
print("Hello")
print("World!")
```

It outputs:

```
>>> Hello
>>> World!
```

Because the end of each string is given '\n' which tells the system to output anything after it on a new line.

---

On the contrary, if you were to do this:

```
print("Hello", end=' ')
print("World!")
```

It would output:

```
>>> Hello World!
```

Because "\n" is no longer added to "Hello" but instead " " which means when "World!" is outputted, it is placed in the same line as "Hello".

---

To fix your problem, just remove `end=''` from your print function.

Comment: Just removing `end=""` will result in different than the expected output.

Comment: @tobias_k When I posted my answer, the OP didn't specify the intended output and the way the question was worded made it so that it seems that he wanted it not to output on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add another `print()` after the inner loop, ending in a normal line break.

```
loop=int(input())
while loop>0:
    in_val=input()
    leni = len(in_val)
    while leni>0:
        print(in_val[leni-1],end='') # Here printed the same line 
        leni-=1 # Here the loop ends
    print()
    loop-=1
```

Also, you can replace the `while` loops with `for` loops that maintain their own loop variables:

```
loop=int(input())
for _ in range(loop):
    in_val=input()
    for i in range(len(in_val)):
        print(in_val[-1-i], end='') # Here printed the same line 
    print()
```

Next, you could replace the inner loop with a list-comprehension and `"".join`. This way, you only have one `print` in the loop, thus `end=""` is not needed.

```
loop=int(input())
for _ in range(loop):
    in_val=input()
    print("".join(in_val[-1-i] for i in range(len(in_val))))
```

Finally, you can just use `in_val[::-1]` to reverse the string.

```
loop=int(input())
for _ in range(loop):
    in_val=input()
    print(in_val[::-1])
```